# List Item Shown Top of The List

Tags: list, item

I created a list on Sharepoint Designer 2013.

When I add new item in the list, the item isn't showing top of list. I want to shown last item top of the list.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you changed the Sort in the view-settings? If you order the list by ID and Descending it should work as you describe.

Comment: List of creating mixed.For example, I create a new item, it looks in the middle of the list. @RobertLindgren

Comment: I understand, and I am guessing that is related to the Sort being made on another column than the ID. Hence you should Modify the All Items view and set the Sort to be on ID column and descending